# How to disable log feature of less command?

Tags: less

I use the `less` command a lot to view files, but when viewing a file, sometimes accidentally I type the `s` key within `less`, activating then the `log` feature. If I don't notice that `log` in the bottom of the terminal and keep typing (such as searching for a pattern), a file may be created in the current directory.

According to `man less`, there is a "secure" mode for `less`, when the environment variable `LESSSECURE` is set to 1, but this will disable several more features, I only want to disable the `log` feature.

I never use the log feature in `less`. How can I disable the `log` feature of `less`?

Answer (score 7):

Create a file setting a new key binding for the `s` command key, and
"compile it" as follows:

```
echo 's invalid' >~/.lesskey
lesskey
```

Then typing `s` in less will just beep or flash.

Comment: Yes it works as expected, but I created an alias in my `.bashrc`, so my less is actually `less -RM -s +Gg`, so I'm wondering if the `making-s-invalid` can be set into the `alias`, since I have to type commands and compile the file into another file ~/.less if using your solution.

Comment: I dont think you can make it an option to the `less` command. But you only need to run `lesskey` once. Why not add it in your `~/.bash_profile` if you dont want to forget it. You can specify a different place for the `.less` file.